# Delivery Date Javascript Adapt To Exclude Weekends

Tags: javascript, date

I have been currently using this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _next = new Date(new Date() * 1 + 24*60*60*1000*9);
document.write(" Your expected delivery date is " + (_next.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + _next.getDate() + "/" + _next.getFullYear());
</script>
```

I'm wondering how do I get it to exclude weekends if possible.

Comment: Your code currently adds 9 days to the current date, regardless of the current day of the week. What behavior do you want? (e.g. add 9 days to today, then find the next weekday after that; alternatively, add 9 business days to today)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add hours if you like. this is a code that expects to deliver the next working day.

```
function myFunction() { 
var d = new Date();
var weekday = new Array(7);
weekday[0] = "sunday";
weekday[1] = "monday";
weekday[2] = "tuesday";
weekday[3] = "wednesday";
weekday[4] = "thursday";
weekday[5] = "friday";
weekday[6] = "saturday";
var monthday = new Array(12);
monthday[0] = "01";
monthday[1] = "02";
monthday[2] = "03";
monthday[3] = "04";
monthday[4] = "05";
monthday[5] = "06";
monthday[6] = "07";
monthday[7] = "08";
monthday[8] = "09";
monthday[9] = "10";
monthday[10] = "11";
monthday[11] = "12";


if (d.getDay() > 0 && d.getDay() <= 4) {
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 24);
    var deliver = weekday[d.getDay()];
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = monthday[d.getMonth()];
    var year = d .getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("deliveryday").innerHTML = deliver + ' ' + day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
} else if (d.getDay() == 0) {
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 48);
    var deliver = weekday[d.getDay()];
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = monthday[d.getMonth()];
    var year = d .getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("deliveryday").innerHTML = deliver + ' ' + day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
} else {
    d.setHours(d.getHours() + 72);
    var deliver = weekday[d.getDay()];
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = monthday[d.getMonth()];
    var year = d .getFullYear();
    document.getElementById("deliveryday").innerHTML = deliver + ' ' + day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
}
myFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function deliver(inDays, startingOn){
  var s, f = 0, d;
  if(!inDays)inDays = 0;
  s = !startingOn ? new Date : new Date(startingOn);
  for(var i=0,n,t=0,l=inDays; i<l; i++,t+=86400000){
    n = new Date(s.getTime()+t).getDay();
    if(n === 0 || n === 6)f++;
  }
  d = new Date(s.getTime()+86400000*(inDays+f));
  return 'Your expected delivery date is '+d.toLocaleDateString();
}
// same day delivery
console.log(deliver());
// deliver in 9 days stating today
console.log(deliver(9));
// deliver in 9 days starting on October 12, 2013 - must be a valid Date String
console.log(deliver(9, 'October 12, 2013'));
/* Note that in the last example the Date starts on the weekend, therefore same
   day becomes Monday, which if you don't work weekends is the first day you
   would see the order anyways.
*/
```

This is good to show your Client when something is delivered. Make sure you set the actual date it your database, according to where you are, using a Server Side language like PHP.

You should pay me for this since it will work even on a leap year. Ha!

Comment: Have been working on this over the weekend here is what I have when the days are lower below 5 seems to work ok unsure where I have went wrong now any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<!--
var myDate=new Date();
if ( myDate.getHours() < 12 ) // less than 12pm
  {
  var daystodeliver = [7,5,5,5,5,8,7][myDate.getDay()];
  }
else
  {
  var daystodeliver = [7,7,7,7,7,9,8][myDate.getDay()];
  }
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate()+daystodeliver);
document.write(['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']     [myDate.getDay()]);
var dayofmonth =  myDate.getDate();
suffix = ((dayofmonth < 10)||(dayofmonth > 20)) ?   ['th','st','nd','rd','th','th','th','th','th','th'][dayofmonth % 10] : 'th';
document.write(' ' + dayofmonth + suffix + ' ');
 document.write(['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','Septembe    r','October','November','December'][myDate.getMonth()]);
// -->
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this to get the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297323/calculate-an-expected-delivery-date-accounting-for-holidays-in-business-days-u/21369745#21369745)

I wrote a routine that you supply a date object, apply the menthod, the public holidays in a separate list is passed and any holidays / public holidays including weekends are skipped over.

Its this post

```
// array of ISO YYYY-MM-DD format dates
publicHolidays = {
  uk:["2020-01-01","2020-04-10","2020-04-13","2020-05-08","2020-05-25",
    "2020-08-03","2020-08-31","2020-12-25","2020-12-28"],
   usa:["2020-01-01","2020-01-20","2020-02-14","2020-02-17","2020-04-10",
    "2020-04-12","2020-05-10","2020-05-25","2020-06-21","2020-07-03",
    "2020-07-04","2020-09-07","2020-10-12","2020-10-31","2020,11,11",
    "2020-11-26","2020-12-25"]
}
// check if there is a match in the array
Date.prototype.isPublicHoliday = function( data ){// we check for a public holiday
    if(!data) return 1;
return data.indexOf(this.toISOString().slice(0,10))>-1? 0:1;
}

// calculation of business days
Date.prototype.businessDays = function( d, holidays ){
    var holidays = holidays || false, t = new Date( this ); // copy date.  
    while( d ){ // we loop while d is not zero...       
    t.setDate( t.getDate() + 1 ); // set a date and test it
    switch( t.getDay() ){ // switch is used to allow easier addition of other days of the week
            case 0: case 6: break;// sunday & saturday
            default: // check if we are a public holiday or not
            d -= t.isPublicHoliday( holidays ); 
        } 

    }
    return t.toISOString().slice(0,10); // just the YYY-MM-DD 
}

// dummy var, could be a form field input
OrderDate = "2020-02-12";
// test with a UK holiday date
var deliveryDate = new Date(OrderDate).businessDays(7, publicHolidays.usa);
// expected output 2020-02-25
console.log("Order date: %s, Delivery date: %s",OrderDate,deliveryDate );
```