# to exclude saturday and Sunday when duration is given from today's date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can we exclude Saturday and Sunday when a duration is given from the user. Duration should be counted from today's date. Example today's date is 2/2/2018 n duration is 20 days. So calculate the date when 20 days will be over starting from today excluding Saturday and Sunday. Duration can varry , it depends upon user. And code should be in JavaScript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add business days in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297323/how-do-i-add-business-days-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript's `moment` library for the purpose. You can read the documentation here:  https://momentjs.com/docs/. You can implement this something similarly in this way:

```
let today = moment();

while(duration > 0) {
   if (today.day() !== 5 || today.day() !== 6) { // 5 is for Saturday and 6 is for Sunday. 
     today.add(1, 'days');
     duration -= 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: make sure you have added moment library to your project correctly, and look at the documentation for how to do that